# How to set the folder for an embedded Shell activeX control in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, windows-shell

If I was just automating the shell directly as opposed it embedding it, it would look something like this :

```
string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
shell.Explore(curDir);
```

However, my goal is to embed it into my windows form.  This is what I have so far:

- So, I have added a COM reference to `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` (Shell32.dll)
- I have added a COM control in the winforms toolbar via choose items to the `Microsoft Shell Folder View Router`
- I have dragged the control to my form so I have access to it in a variable called `axShellFolderViewOC1`

My code so far looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Shell32;
using AxShell32;

namespace winforms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            var comObject= axShellFolderViewOC1.GetOcx();
            var comInterface = comObject as  //what goes here?

            //pseudo code
            comInterface.Explore(curDir);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way.  Use the WebBrowser control instead.  If you need access to the ShellFolderView, cast the `WebBrowser.ActiveXInstance` to a `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`.  the SHDocVw.InternetExplorer's Document property will be an instance of ShellFolderView.

Comment: This is helpful, but I would prefer to avoid the web browser control. I already knew how to directly navigate the file system via the web browser control, I am specifically looking for an alternative.

Comment: I'll be interested to see if someone has alternative to the IE control, but Shell's file explorer window is an instance of InternetExplorer (see: [ShellWindows object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx).  I recently posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48179225/2592875) on closing open file explorer windows that you may find of interest.

Comment: What proposes TnTinMn is the easiest way. I don't think ShellFolderViewOC supports anything else than IE's document (I'd be happy to be wrong). Note WebOC (although it sounds Web is really generic https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/12/30/in-place-shell-navigation-with-the-webbrowser-control-on-windows-7/) Another way is to host IExplorerBrowser (Vista+), but these interfaces must be declared manually to be used in C#, it's more work and in the end it will probably be more or less the same thing, using the same dlls, etc.